# Insertar un campo válido(letras y no números) en mysql con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola buenas noches comunidad!!

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un sitio en el cual por medio de un formulario se ingresan datos sin problema a la BD ya saben lo típico, guardo variable y mando llamar por método post y con un query guardo (Imagen1). 
Pero lo que quiero saber es que por ejemplo al momento de escribir en la caja de texto un nombre o materia, aunque en este caso nombre de un profesor sería: 
**M. EN T.I Pablito Ruiz** lo guarda bien porque en la estructura el dato es VARCHAR
pero si escribo *puros números* en esa caja de texto del nombre del profesor igual me lo va a guardar.
Y lo puse en varchar por lo mismo como el nombre necesita de puntos "."
¿Habrá alguna forma de que sólo se puedan guardar letras y no números? 
Algo así tipo un script que lance un mensaje de "Datos no válidos"

```
 [![imagen1][1]][1]
```

Espero que me haya dado a entender y muchas gracias por sus comentarios y su tiempo!!

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando recibes los datos valida que no tenga números u otro carácter que no quieras. Puedes usar [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) o [strpbrk()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpbrk.php) por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

**varchar** es un tipo de datos para almacenar cadenas de texto de longitud variable. Las cadenas están compuestas de caracteres y los números dentro de una cadena son un carácter más, por lo ue el uso de varchar no va a eliminarlos.

Puedes sin embargo, procesar la cadena para eliminar los caracteres de números antes de enviar el dato a mysql, ejemplo

Remplazar los números por una cadena vacía.

```
$numeros = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
$sin_numeros = str_replace($numeros, "", "x3r1f");

echo $sin_numeros; // xrf
```

También  podrías aplicar un remplazo de algunos números por las letras más comunes, o pasar un 4 parámetro para saber cuantos remplazos hubo, ejemplo:

```
$numeros = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
$remplazo = array("o", "i", "z", "e", "a", "", "", "t", "", "");
$sin_numeros = str_replace($numeros, $remplazo, "x3r1f", $count);

echo $sin_numeros; // xerif
echo 'se remplazaron '. $count .' numeros';
```

Documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Gracias, bro!! he leído la documentación y quedó, pero encontré otra forma con el "pattern" en el código de HTML añadiendo letras de la A-Z
Saludos y gracias.